# Yandex Maps API. Панорамы по дате снимка

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При использовании сервиса панорам в Яндекс-картах есть возможность выбирать год снимка через специальный контрол.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли сделать то же с помощью Yandex Maps JavaScript API? При использовании API по умолчанию в плеере открывается самая свежая панорама, а контрол указания года отсутствует.

Может быть, можно как-нибудь реализовать?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью Yandex Maps JavaScript API такое сделать нельзя.