# Yandex Maps API. Получить год панорамы

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты, панорамы

В Yandex Maps есть контрол с выбором года панорамы.
При внедрении панорамы на свою страницу такого контрола нет.
Я читал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/974395/190166), и понял, что такой же контрол у себя никак не получить.

Но есть ли возможность хотя бы **узнать год** отображаемой панорамы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только вручную на карте Яндекс.

API Яндекс.Карт не транслирует информацию о дате съёмки ни в каком виде. Выбрать нужный год съёмки тоже возможности нет.